# wp sign on against user role

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I'm using this code-

```
$info = array();
    $info['user_login'] = $_POST['username'];
    $info['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
    $info['remember'] = true;

    $user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );

    if ( is_wp_error($user_signon) ){
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Wrong username or password.')));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=>__('Login successful, redirecting...')));
    }

    die();
```

Login is working fine.But how can i restrict a user with editor role in this function so that i can check the role and if its there then i will pass a custom error message in the json?

Answer (score 1):

To restrict a specific user role, first you should check the users roles. If the users has the restricted roles, then simply don't perform login operation and through a error message, else sign-in the user by `wp_signon`. Here is the complete code should look like.

```
$info                  = array();
$info['user_login']    = $_POST['username'];
$info['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
$info['remember']      = true;
$user                  = get_user_by( 'login', $info['user_login'] );

if ( $user && in_array( 'editor', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
  echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Editors are restricted.')));

}else{

  $user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );

  if ( is_wp_error($user_signon) ){
    echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Wrong username or password.')));
  } else {
    echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=>__('Login successful, redirecting...')));
  }

}
```

Comment: okay if in the array i find the role then how can i prevent the user from logging in with is wp error function?

can you please send me a detail code with my function?